# How to vectorize this Matlab loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I need some help to vectorize the following operation since I'm a little confused.

So, I have a `m`-by-2 matrix `A` and `n`-by-1 vector `b`. I want to create a `n`-by-1 vector `c` whose entries should be the values of the second column of `A` whose line is given by the line where the correspondent value of `b` would fall...

Not sure if I was clear enough. Anyway, the code below does compute `c` correctly so you can understand what is my desired output. However, I want to vectorize this function since my real `n` and `m` are in the order of many thousands.

Note that values of `b`are non-integer and not necessarily equal to any of those in the first column of `A` (these ones could be non-integers too!).

```
m = 5; n = 10;

A = [(0:m-1)*1.1;rand(1,m)]'
b = (m-1)*rand(n,1)

[bincounts, ind] = histc(b,A(:,1))

for i = 1:n
    c(i) = A(ind(i),2);
end
```

Comment: @Divakar Well... yes, I believe that's actually the solution! :) Would you place an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
c = A(ind,2);
```

Comment: I was not clear enough. `b` could be non-integer and may not match exactly any of the values in `A(:,1)`

Comment: You were close! Edit with `c = A(ind,2)`? Also, for the updated code, even `c = A(ceil(b),2)` seems to work to avoid `histc`.

Comment: @Divakar I'm afraid the second solution using `ceil()` is not viable, since `A(:,1)` are random non-integer monotonically increasing numbers.

Comment: @Divakar Sounds like you should get the credit here. Maybe add your own answer?

Comment: @eigenchris Oh no, you got it right before the edits in the question, you do it! Make sure to do the edits in the solution code that worked for OP.